# Objective c select statement

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

hey guys im trying to do a SELECT Statement from a local SQLDB
so my statement is something like
select ..etc..etc WHERE Date =%@,theDate

theDate is an NSString variable.
i NSLoged theDate and it returned 22/06/2010

But it doesnt work so i tried the following
select ..etc..etc WHERE DATE ='22/06/2010'

And the values came by. any idea why this happens?
In the SQLDB, the column type for DATE is NVARCHAR though. does that matters?

Comment: Why have you tagged this iPhone?

Comment: you might want to mention (in your question text too) that you are trying to develop an cocoa / iphone / objective-c app, and include the statement that constructs the query.

Comment: i'm guessing based on the NSString datatype and the =%@ that this is objective C, most probably iphone related. should be tagged so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from your question it looks like including single quotes around the %@ token might be worth a shot

```
"select....etc. etc. ...WHERE Date ='%@'",theDate
```